# Axios POST res.data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, state

I have a function which calls an `axios.post`, this function returns the obejct to the main react App, which should then save it / show it on the screen.

The return of the "postData" function (in API) looks like this:

```
return axios.post(url, object).then((res) => res.data);
```

In the main react app, I have:

```
async postData (file1, file2, algorithm) {
   this.setState({
        anomalies: await api.postData(file1, file2, algorithm)
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.anomalies); }
    )
}
```

When I `console.log` the anomalies (as in code), I get undefined.
In addition, I have a div as:

```
<div> {this.state.anomalies} <div/>
```

Which shows relevant content, but after the call doesn't show anything.

If I do:

```
axios.post(url, object).then((res) => console.log(res.data);
```

I get the correct object printed. So then how can I pass this object in the correct way to the React app?

Thanks!

Comment: Logging the state immediately after updating it will log the old value because state is updated asynchronously and state is constant within a particular render of the component. To log the updated state, you can use the second optional argument to `this.setState` which is a callback function that is invoked _after_ the state has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the code (see edit), but still undefined is printed.

Answer (score 0):

App.js file

```
import React from "react";

import API from "./API";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { anomalies: null };
  }

  post = async () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        anomalies: await API.postData()
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.anomalies);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.post}> click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

API.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'


function postData () {
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then( res =>  res.data)
}


export default {
  postData
}
```